# How to provide dependency of List Adapter class using dagger hilt? - when adapter class takes interface as a parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, interface, dagger-2, listadapter, dagger-hilt

**suppose this is a interface**

```
interface Listener {

    fun deleteOnClick(position:Int,userId:Int)

    fun updateOnClick(position: Int,userId: Int,name:String,phoneNo:Long)
}
```

**And this is my Adapter class, where i am passing listener interface as a parameter**

```
class PhoneAdapter
@Inject
constructor(private val listener: Listener) : ListAdapter<Phone,PhoneAdapter.PhoneViewHolder>(Diff) {

    inner class PhoneViewHolder(private val binding: EachRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(phone: Phone){
            binding.apply {
                name.text = phone.name
                phoneNo.text = phone.phoneNo.toString()
                delete.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.deleteOnClick(adapterPosition,phone.userId)
                }
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.updateOnClick(adapterPosition,phone.userId,phone.name,phone.phoneNo)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    object Diff : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Phone>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Phone, newItem: Phone): Boolean {
            return oldItem.userId == newItem.userId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Phone, newItem: Phone): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhoneViewHolder {
        return PhoneViewHolder(EachRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhoneViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val phone = getItem(position)
        if(phone != null){
            holder.bind(phone)
        }
    }
}
```

**And MainActivity implementing this interface**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Listener {
    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }
....
....
}
```

So my question is how to provide dependency of Listener interface..

Comment: I don't get the answer. Where do you want to provide what? Do you need the adapter inside your activity? Then field inject it via @Inject lateinit var adapter: PhoneAdapter

Comment: yes i want to inject adapter class in MainActivity but adapter class takes interface as a parameter and i am unable to provide the dependency of interface, can you please check this?

Comment: well, kind of late to answer this question, but check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70729590/how-to-inject-lambdaor-interface-at-runtime-with-hilt/70765176#70765176