# How to inject lambda(or interface) at runtime with hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm using hilt with MVVM, RecyclerView

I wanna inject a lambda into the Adapter for receiving clickListeners from child views,
but with @Module, I cannot create lambda at runtime.

[Snippets below]

```
// Lambda Listener
class CustomAdapter @Inject constructor(private val listener: (clickedItem: Object) -> Unit) {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.invoke(clickedItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject lambda or interface at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best option, but you can use `AssistedInjection`.

Firstly, you need to create an `interface` with the `AssistedFactory` annotation

```
@AssistedFactory
interface Factory {
    fun create(
        listener: (keyName: String) -> Unit
    ): CustomAdapter
}
```

Secondly: Replace `@Inject` with `@AssistedInject` in your adapter and add your listener in the constructor with the `@Assisted` annotation

```
class CustomAdapter @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val listener: (keyName: String) -> Unit
)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
    CustomViewHolder(CustomViewHolderBinding.inflate(....), listener)
```

Finally, in your fragment/activity, you need to inject the `factory` instead of your adapter, and use it to create the `adapter`

```
@Inject
lateinit var customAdapterFactory: CustomAdapter.Factory

val listener = (keyName: String) -> Unit = { keyName ->
    ......
}
val customAdapter = customAdapterFactory.create(listener)
```